# Question on Sigma Algebras

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have the measure spaces $(\mathscr{X},\mathscr{A},\mu_1), (\mathscr{Y},\mathscr{B},\mu_2), and(\mathscr{Z},\mathscr{C},\mu_3)$. I take the $\sigma$-algebra $F=\{E\in(\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B})\times\mathscr{C}:E\in\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{C}\}$.

I want to fix $C\in\mathscr{C}$ and take $F_1=\{E\in\mathscr{X}\times\mathscr{Y}:E\times Z\in F\}$. My goal is to argue that $F_1$ contains all sets of the form $E\times C$. I know that $F_1$ contains some such sets but if I can argue that all of them lie in $F_1$ then it follows that *F* and $F_1$ coincide since *F* will be the least $\sigma$-algebra containing these sets. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $F$. Why are you distinguishing between $(\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B})\times\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{C}$?